# Authentication between a java and .net application

Tags: java, .net, authentication

We have a .net application which uses asp.net SQL membership provider for authentication purpose. We are now introducing a java application which needs to be integrated with the .NET application in terms of authentication, so users wont have to login again going from the java to the .net application. What would be the best approach to a SSO solution?

I would greatly appreciate your input.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's look at what we know:

1. Authentication code for ASP.NET is done using Membership API (.NET)
2. Java web site needs to access this code

So, in order for 2) to happen, you need to do the following:

- **Expose** .NET Authentication code on Web Site A (ASP.NET)
- **Consume** .NET Authentication code on Web Site B (Java)

If your >= .NET 3.0, i'd recommend **WCF**, if not, you're stuck with classic **ASMX**.

Expose operations (SignIn, SignOut, etc) via the WCF/ASMX Service which can then be consumed by the Java client (JSON would be best, but could always use XML/SOAP).

There is a really nice 4-part tutorial on SSO with WCF [here](http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2009/07/01/building-single-sign-on-provider-using.aspx).

Even if you don't end up going with WCF, the tutorial still has a lot of helpful info.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.If the entry point for a user is the java app where they type in their username/pwd and which is validated using WCF, would they have to login again when they land on the .net application. I know that if both the applications are .NET, the auth cookie generated by the .net framework allows users to go from one app to another with re logging in. Is that same case with this solution?

Comment: "one app to another with re logging in" - i meant without re-logging in.

Comment: Yes, you just need to use custom auth cookies, not the regular ASPX auth. Facebook does a very similar thing with Facebook Connect - after you login to facebook, when you go to a Facebook-Connect-site, it checks with Facebook if the user is authenticated (asks forcookies).

Answer (score 1):

You could also call the membership provider stored procedures from the java application.